# Thank you for your kind notice. (when can be used?)

Tags: sentence-usage

Thank you for your kind notice...
Can be used when you shared a document to your boss and he went through it in detailed and asked you further questions on it? After replying to those questions, can we type - Thank you for your kind notice!

Comment: It's not idiomatic in my (British) English. I would say "Thank you for kindly (going through/checking/helping me with) my document."